# xelatex conflicts with "songs" package when setting default language

Tags: xetex, songs

The problem is xelatex won't compile if I'm trying to use `\gtab` from "songs" package. That's minimal example that reproduces this annoying xelatex behavior:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{songs}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}  % If comment this line - it compiles and works, but makes a lot of other errors o_O

\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Arial}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Courier New}

\begin{document}

{\gtab{A}{X02220:001230}}\par

\end{document}
```

The error is completely unrelated:

```
Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain
the Cyrillic script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \cyrillicfont with \newfontfamily.
```

As you see, `\newfontfamily` was set with `\cyrillicfont`.
And surprisingly, I figured out that if I comment `\setdefaultlanguage` line, everything compiles.

But that's not a good solution because if I remove `\setdefaultlanguage`, all the other part of document will break (It's Russian, that's why I use `\setdefaultlanguage`).

Finally that looks really riddiculous when such unrelated parts of tex are conflicting with each other.

Does anybody know about any good workarounds?

Answer (score 5):

The error message is wrong, you are not missing `\cyrillicfont` for the roman family, but a cyrillic font for `\sffamily`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{songs}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}  % 
%
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Arial}[Script=Cyrillic]
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Courier New}[Script=Cyrillic]
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontsf}{Arial}[Script=Cyrillic]
\begin{document}
abc {\sffamily abc}

{\gtab{A}{X02220:001230}}\par

\end{document}
```